# Can you replace an em-dash with a comma?

Tags: grammar, commas, em-dashes

If I were to say something like

> This is something that is revolutionary—that will redefine our society.

Can you use a comma instead of an em dash? In all cases? What are the rules?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Do you have a context in which you're thinking of? There are formal rules for academic articles as outlined by style guides such as the APA guide, or academic and/or general printed matter (Harvard, Chicago, Oxford), but usage can differ for high-end news outlets, lower-end new outlets, general publications, and poetry - depending on purpose and audience. Also, I'd argue that if your desired effect is to emphasise the second part of the sentence, you would be better served by rhetoric than puncutation - use of repetition, for example.

Comment: Clean and simple:  This is revolutionary and will redefine our society.